# Show that $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{f(cx)}{f(x)}=1, ∀c>0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Lef $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a monotone function such that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(2x)}{f(x)} =1$. Show that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(cx)}{f(x)}=1,  ∀c>0$.

Comment: "Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level."

Comment: @GabrielRomon I have given that ε>0 exists A>0 such that yes x∈X and x>A then | f(2x)/f(x) - 1| < ε

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First show this for $c$ a power of $2$, by breaking it into a product of ratios like $\frac{f(8x)}{f(x)} = \frac{f(2\cdot 4x)}{f(4x)}\cdot\frac{f(2\cdot 2x)}{f(2x)}\cdot\frac{f(2\cdot x)}{f(x)}$.  The use monotonicity to finish it off for arbutrary $c$ by choosing a power of $2$, say $2^n$, that is greater than $c$ so that $f(cx)$ is between $f(x)$ and $f(2^nx)$.

Comment: How do you take care of the case $c<1$?

Comment: Two ways: (a) You can get it from the case of $\frac{1}{c}$, which would be greater than 1. (b) The original hypothesis pretty directly gives the result for $c=\frac{1}{2}$ (just invert the fraction and you still have limit 1...then substitute $y=\frac{x}{2}$).  Then you can apply the same argument with powers of $\frac{1}{2}$ instead of powers of 2.